# Add angular content in link stage of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, tooltip, angularjs-compile

I'm trying to make a custom tooltip that contains a table populated by ng-repeat.

My directive looks like the following:

```
app.directive('picker', function ($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element) {
         $(element).popover({
            title: 'picker',
            content: $compile('<table class="..."><tbody><tr ng-repeat="item in pickerItems">...</tr></tbody></table>')(scope),
            html: true
         });
         $compile()
      }
   };
});
```

When I open the page, the tooltip shows but the content is empty. In dev tools I see the table but the tbody looks like

```
<tbody> ngRepeat: item in pickerItems </tbody>
```

Any ideas how to compile that section?

Comment: could you create a plunker,http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Give a try $compile(element)(scope) at the end instead of compiling the content.